# com_example.android.softkeyboard launch fails

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have imported existing project from com_example.android.softkeyboard from sdk sample code.
When I tried to run it launch get cancel and it give some error as follows

[2013-01-07 22:09:45 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] ------------------------------
[2013-01-07 22:09:45 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Android Launch!
[2013-01-07 22:09:45 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-07 22:09:45 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-01-07 22:09:45 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-01-07 22:09:45 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Performing sync
[2013-01-07 22:10:00 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2013-01-07 22:10:00 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.4)
[2013-01-07 22:10:00 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Uploading com_example_android_softkeyboard.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-01-07 22:10:00 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Installing com_example_android_softkeyboard.apk...
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.softkeyboard' in a shell.
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Launch canceled!

Please help me to run application.

Answer (score 0):

The log tells you exactly what the problem is and how to fix it:

```
Installing com_example_android_softkeyboard.apk... 
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data! 
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.softkeyboard' in a shell. 
[2013-01-07 22:10:17 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Launch canceled!
```

There is already a version of `com.example.android.softkeyboard` installed on your emulator and you need to remove (uninstall) that one before you install your new one.